# How to efficiently look a value in a multi level dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the below dictionary.

```
mapper = { "Pog-345": {"DFH":['13062519','13063013','13063543','13072434','13123190']}
 ,"Pog-347": {"Hetive":['82722892'],"TFH":['14326471','50059137','54250307','15681953','76433609'],} 
 , "Poh-45": {}  }
```

How can I check a key is in the dictionary. For example, I want to know this key "Poh-45" is inside the dictionary. (Since my actual dictionary is way bigger than this I need some efficient code)
How can I do that in the multilevel dictionary?
If the key is in there and not empty I want to do some calculations, if the key isn't there I want to go to the next step. Can someone give me an idea, please?
Anything is appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: `if key is in mapper`?

Comment: yes key is in the mapper. I mean how can I check whether this value "Poh-45" is inside the dictionary.

Comment: yes it's a nested dic

Comment: `"Poh-45" in mapper` is truthy, so you can do it exactly like that

Comment: Do you only care about the keys of `mapper`, as opposed to the keys in the values in `mapper`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursion:

```py
def check_key(d, k):
    for i in d:
        if isinstance(i, dict):
            return check_key(d)
        elif i == k:
            return True
    return False
```

Example:

```py
>>> print(check_key(mapper, 'Pog-347'))
True
>>> print(check_key(mapper, 'og-347'))
False
```